# JavaScript passing parameter event

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner in JavaScript I find mostly this syntax

```
<body  onclick="myFunction(event)">
```

or

```
<button ....>
```

1. Why we use  event as parameter
2. what the difference between event and Event in javascript

Answer (score 2):

The event only needs to be passed if the function *does something* with the event. For example, you might want to examine the clicked element, which can be done by looking at the `.target` of the event:

```js
function foo(event) {
  console.log(event.target.id);
}
```

```html
<button id="thebutton" onclick="foo(event)">click</button>
```

If you don't pass `event`, the `foo` function won't be able to see the event as the argument.

That said, in modern JavaScript, you should really never be using inline handlers, they have quite a few problems and are widely considered to be poor practice. Better to use `addEventListener`:

```js
function foo(event) {
  console.log(event.target.id);
}
document.querySelector('#thebutton').addEventListener('click', foo);
```

```html
<button id="thebutton">click</button>
```

> what the difference between event and Event in javascript

`Event` is a *constructor* function which can create events.

```
const someEvent = new Event('click');
```

In contrast, the `event` you see in inline handlers refers to `window.event`, which is the event that resulted in the current handler running.